# How to print multiple object values in jsp file using c:forEach in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, h2

I'm new to Spring Boot framework. I am trying to print/show multiple rows from the database in jsp file. I am able to print the single object value in the jsp file but unable to print multiple object values.
These are the dependency in my pom.xml file.

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is the model.

```
package com.basic.crudapp.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue //it auto increments the id column value starting from 1
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String content;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", content='" + content + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

This is the controller...

```
package com.basic.crudapp.controller;

import com.basic.crudapp.dao.PostRepo;
import com.basic.crudapp.model.Post;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    PostRepo repo;


    @RequestMapping("/getAllPosts")
    public ModelAndView allPost() {
        // setting the view name using constructor
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("post/index");
        Iterable<Post> posts = repo.findAll();
        mv.addObject(posts);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

This is the PostRepo...

```
package com.basic.crudapp.dao;

import com.basic.crudapp.model.Post;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PostRepo extends CrudRepository<Post, Integer> {

}
```

And at last this is the jsp file..

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>JSP page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h3>List of all posts</h3>
            <c:forEach items="${posts}" var="post">
                <tr>
                    <td>${post.id}</td>
                    <td>${post.title}</td>
                    <td>${post.content}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have inserted five rows in the Post table in my database manually using data.sql file in the resources directory.

Where I'm doing mistake ? Sorry for the long post, but I'm new to this framework that is why I posted the whole situation. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe `mv.addObject("posts", posts);` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solves my problem. :)